# unable to validate the string using equalsIgnoreCase returning false

Tags: java, selenium

[image: this is how my data looks]

```
expectedResult= Predictive
sourceVal = PEDP
actual value is  Enforcement Type Predictive PEDP
```

Here if i use equalsIgnoreCase it is failing because it couldn't match the string .  Please suggest on how i can effectively validate the second and third column values

```
 public void validateKeyInfo_1(String expectedResult, String elementId, String sourceVal) {
    String actualValue = getElement(elementId).getText();
    boolean result = false;
    result = (expectedResult == null && StringUtils.isBlank(actualValue)) || (expectedResult != null && expectedResult.equalsIgnoreCase(actualValue));
    if (result) {
      scenario.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Value for element id : " + expectedResult + " is " + actualValue);
      if (actualValue.contains(sourceVal)) {
        scenario.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Value for source is : " + sourceVal + " is " + sourceVal);
      } else {
        reportFailure("Element value did not match with expected result");
      }
    } else {
      reportFailure("Element value did not match with expected result");
    }
  }
```

Comment: put a sysout at very beginning to see what have we got for `expectedResult` ?

Comment: `expectedResult == null &&`

Comment: I am getting the actual value as -  Enforcement Type Predictive PEDP

Answer (score 0):

Since `actualValue` is `Enforcement Type Predictive PEDP` and `expectedResult= Predictive` you definitely have to use `contains()` or `containsIgnoreCase()` methods, not `equalsIgnoreCase()` method and you should validate that `actualValue` contains `expectedResult` as following:

```java
String actualValue = getElement(elementId).getText();
boolean result = false;
result = (expectedResult == null && StringUtils.isBlank(actualValue)) || (expectedResult != null && actualValue.containsIgnoreCase(expectedResult));
```

Comment: i have used contains and also also used .trim . its still the same .. the method is returning false

Comment: I know! You should check if `actualValue` contains `expectedResult`!

Comment: @Prophet : If expected and actual values are different then test case should fail, OP should and must use equals to check the content, not contains.

Comment: If so he should extract the relevant part from `actualValue` to make it comparable with the `expectedResult`

Answer (score 0):

I have bit modification and replaced that .isBlank method, while testing in my local I have hardcoded the values to replicate the same issue, Please try :

```
public static void validateKeyInfo_1(String expectedResult, String elementId, String sourceVal) {
    String actualValue = "Enforcement Type Predictive PEDP";
    expectedResult = "Predictive";
    boolean result = false;
    result = (expectedResult == null && actualValue.isEmpty()) || (expectedResult != null && expectedResult.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(actualValue));
    if (result) {
      scenario.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Value for element id : " + expectedResult + " is " + actualValue);
      if (actualValue.contains(sourceVal)) {
        scenario.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Value for source is : " + sourceVal + " is " + sourceVal);
      } else {
        reportFailure("Element value did not match with expected result");
      }
    } else {
      reportFailure("Element value did not match with expected result");
    }
  }
```

basically this `expectedResult.trim() == null && actualValue.trim().isEmpty()` will help you go inside.
Also please remove or comment these two lines while executing in your local.

```
String actualValue = "Enforcement Type Predictive PEDP";
expectedResult = "Predictive";
```

Comment: @user16320675 : Yes you are right, I should have never used .trim when comparing to null.